# jQuery AJAX load not executing on ASP.NET MVC Controller Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a simple thing going here: two divs and two calls to load partials (controller actions with PartialView as results).

I am dealing with two controller actions: Index and ItemDetail.  The jQuery load works in the view returned by the Index action, but not on ItemDetail.

These items are in the same controller and you can access them in a brower as follows:
http://[site]/items
http://[site]/items/itemdetail

To isolate the problem, I have set up Index and ItemDetail to return views with identical syntax:

```
<div id="deptTickets">Loading department tickets...</div>
<div id="recentTickets">Loading recent tickets...</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $("#deptTickets").load("items/DepartmentTickets");
    $("#recentTickets").load("items/RecentTickets");
</script>
```

The .load methods fire and load the appropriate partial views for index, but not for ItemDetail.

I think the only thing different is the route.  In fact, if I return the 'detail' view in the index it renders correctly and the jQuery runs, and if I return the 'index' view in the controller action for itemDetail it renders the page but never executes the jQuery.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the URLs relative to the site root otherwise your routes won't be correct.  It's probably best to use the Url helper for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    $("#deptTickets").load("<%= Url.Action( "DepartmentTickets", "Items" ) %>"); 
    $("#recentTickets").load("<%= Url.Action( "RecentTickets", "Items" ) %>"); 
</script>
```

Comment: awesome, worked a treat...should have thought of this as I needed to use the Url helper in site.master to get the scripts running in the first place.  thanks a ton.

cheers!
-jc

Comment: i ran this code and evaluated the output in the browser, which revealed the error (related to Craig's response as well).  changing the code I originally posted to the following works as well:

    $("#deptTickets").load("/items/DepartmentTickets");


only difference is the forward slash preceding the items controller.

thanks again.
-jc

Comment: That works as long as the application is not in a subfolder of the web site.   If the application isn't located in the document root then hard-coding a path relative to the document root will end up biting you when you don't expect it.  That's why I always use the UrlHelper to generate the paths.  It understands what the virtual path of the application is and always generates the correct url.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative URI, so it will be appended to the current URI. Since that's a different place, your AJAX request is probably 404ing. Use Firebug's net panel or Fiddler to confirm this.

Comment: thanks, Craig, was going to useful your response but I'm not yet worthy ;o).  cheers,
-jc